# Ensure durability with messages when using WCF

Tags: ibm-mq

I am wondering how we can ensure message durability when using websphere MQ and WCF.  I want to be able to have my WCF process pick messages off of the queue and if there is an issue that the applciation encounters (power outage, etc) I don't lose the messages.  I also would like to not have to use a transaction if at all possible because I want to eliminate distributed transactions.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's transactions and there's distributed transactions.  The "right" answer is to use the WMQ 1-phase commit here.  That doesn't have the complexity of XA transactions but it does give you the ability to roll back a message without losing it.  In fact, when using clients you really should be using at least 1-phase commit just to prevent loss of messages.

Short of that there is always the "browse-with-lock, delete-message-under-cursor" method.  I'm pretty sure everything you need to do the browseing, locking and deleting is exposed under .NET but perhaps Shashi will comment and confirm.

Answer (score 2):

WebSphere MQ WCF custom channel has a feature "Assured Delivery" that guarantees that a service request or reply is actioned and not lost. This is the 1-phase commit (also known as SYNC_POINT in) WMQ.

"Assuered Delivery" is a service contract attribute. [Here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzav.doc/un12400_.htm) are more details about the feature.